# Bundle with rollup Vue component that uses web worker

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, web-worker, rollup

my problem is difficult for me to describe clearly, so hopefully you'll understand me.

I'm trying to bundle a Vue component with rollup and publish it on NPM. The component uses a function in which a create a Worker like this

```
new Worker('@/workers/tree-traversal-worker.ts', { type: 'module' })
```

This works perfectly fine in development and is buildable with the vue build command: `vue-cli-service build`. However, I'd ideally like to use rollup for this since it can generate an *esm* format.

I've tried several rollup plugins, namely *rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader*, *@qintx/rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader*, and *rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader'*. The furthest I've gotten with was `@surma/rollup-plugin-off-main-thread` which successfully generated a dedicated worker file and changed the URL in the `new Worker(...)` appropriately during bundle. However, when I try to install it in another Vue project, I get this error in console

```
tree-traversal-worker-bc0e96e1.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

If I understand it correctly, it simply means that the file was not found since it tries to resolve a script with relative path `/tree-traversal-worker-bc0e96e1.js` rather than the actual file stored in *node_modules*.

So my questions are following. Has anyone managed to somehow bundle a Vue component(s) that use web workers (with or without rollup?). And if not, do you think it's better to pursue a solution that would somehow import the script from Worker from a different file or should I look more into a solution that inlines the worker script into a single bundled file (have tried it as well, without success though)

Any help would be much appreciated.
Below is my rollup config that relates only to esm format output

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import minimist from 'minimist';
import postCSS from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import OMT from '@surma/rollup-plugin-off-main-thread';

const postcssConfig = require('../postcss.config');
const esbrowserslist = fs.readFileSync('./.browserslistrc')
  .toString()
  .split('\n')
  .filter((entry) => entry && entry.substring(0, 2) !== 'ie');

const argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));

const projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

const baseConfig = {
  input: 'src/performant-vue-tree.ts',
  plugins: {
    preVue: [
      alias({
        resolve: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue', '.css'],
        entries: {
          '@': path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src'),
        },
      }),
    ],
    replace: {
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      'process.env.ES_BUILD': JSON.stringify('false'),
    },
    vue: {
      css: true,
      compileTemplate: true,
      style: {
        postcssPlugins: [...postcssConfig.plugins],
      },
    },
    /*
    * Has to be used for processing postcss in general
    * Does not resolve postcss in SFC. For that is vue.style.postcssPlugins
    */
    postCSS: {
      extract: false,
      plugins: [],
    },
    babel: {
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
    },
  },
};

const external = [
  'vue',
  'lodash',
  'promise-worker',
  'json-fn',
  '@clr/icons',
  '@clr/icons/shapes/all-shapes',
  'vue-virtual-scroller',
  'vuex',
  'vue-wait',
];

// Customize configs for individual targets
const buildFormats = [];
if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'es') {
  const esConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      dir: 'dist',
      format: 'esm',
      exports: 'named',
    },
    plugins: [
      OMT({
        useEval: true,
        format: 'esm',
      }),
      postCSS(baseConfig.postCSS),
      replace({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.replace,
        'process.env.ES_BUILD': JSON.stringify('true'),
      }),
      ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
      vue(baseConfig.plugins.vue),
      babel({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.babel,
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              targets: esbrowserslist,
            },
          ],
        ],
      }),
      commonjs(),
    ],
  };
  buildFormats.push(esConfig);
}
```

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Comment: I found a good enough solution. I wrote a simple node script that copies the worker file into a static assets folder (public). So then it's accessible even for an npm module. Therefore, when installing this package, one is required to run this script - I named it `postbuild-scripts` in _package.json_, so running `npm run postbuild-scripts` is enough.

You can check the script here
https://github.com/elisiondan/Performant-Vue-Tree/blob/master/scripts/init-worker.js